# jose.exceptions.JWSError: Invalid header string: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 1: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python-requests, jwt, pytest, fastapi

I am trying to test an authenticated route in FASTAPI using the pytest. When I tried to add the authorization header in the HTTP request, am getting the error as below:

```
@pytest.fixture
def authorized_client(client,token):
    client.headers = {
        **client.headers, 
        "Authorization" : f"Bearer {token}"
    }
    print(client.headers)
    return client
```

and JWT error as below: jose.exceptions.JWSError: Invalid header string: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 1: invalid continuation byte

What I am doing wrong here ? Please help me to find my mistake.

Comment: What is the value of `token`? Do you get the same error without the `authorization` header? (i.e. could the issue be with any of the other headers); do you get the same error if you hard code the JWT value? How does that hardcoded value differ to the dynamic `token` value?